# Justify two-column layout (spans)

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/burz4g8s/4/

My HTML contains rows of 2-button pairs. The server-side app outputs the buttons in a JSP loop, so I have no control over individual buttons -- I can't use the `display: table-cell;` to put each one in its own cell and align them, or to put them in different containers; only a generic container can be used in a loop.

I need to align them, and in addition, Col. 2 can be made larger to accommodate the larger values that may appear there. Col. 1 can be shorter. But the goal is that the radio buttons should line up.

Is there an easy CSS solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean line up vertically, so that the radiobuttons on the right side are also above each other?

Comment: Yes, the radio buttons should evenly aligned under each other. Allowing for a slightly short Column 1 and a longer Column 2.

Comment: There are just spans in the HTML, can you modify the JSP-file? I think adding DIVs with proper properties could help.

Comment: Yes, that's the simple solution. The issue is that a very long string in Col.2 will require the generic width to be very large, but the radio buttons can be lined up in a shorter column in #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set a `<br/>` at the start of the form, you can do this with some styling. The direct neighbour (`+`) and direct descendant (`>`) come in handy.

```css
label {
  color: white;
}

span > input + label {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

br + span + span > input + label {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<span>
  Question 1
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="Q1Yes" value="Yes"/><label for="Q1Yes">Yes</label>
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="Q1Yes" value="No"/><label for="Q1No">No</label>
</span>
<br/>
<span>
  Question 2
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2Option1" value="Yes"/><label for="Q2Option1">Short Option</label>
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" name="Q2" id="Q2Option2" value="No"/><label for="Q2Option2">Very Long Option String Extends to the Right</label>
</span>
<br/>
<span>
  Question 3
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3Option1" value="True"/><label for="Q3Option1">True</label>
</span>
<span>
  <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3Option2" value="False"/><label for="Q3Option1">False</label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you pull in css like this?

```
span {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 8em;
}

span:nth-child(4n-1) {
  width: 30em;
}

span:nth-child(4n) {
  clear: left;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

label{
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/burz4g8s/7/